# Critical Section in main thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am developing a simple multi thread web crawler. I am using a sqlite database to store urls that will be scanned.I have only one handle to the database the problem is that the main thread queryes the database in order to spawn new threads.The threads are accessing the same handle but the main thread also.

I have defined critical sections for each of the threads including the main thread. But the main thread keeps executing code eaven if a thread is in a critical section too.

Here is some code :

```
  CreateDb;

  InitializeCriticalSection(critical);

  index := 0;

  repeat
   if threads < THREADS_MAX then
   begin
     EnterCriticalSection(critical);
     try
       sqldb.query('SELECT * FROM urls WHERE vizitat=0 AND id>' + IntToStr(index));
       urlcount:= sqldb.rowcount;

       for i:= 1 to urlcount do
       begin
         WriteLn(sqldb.Fs('adresa'));
         sqldb.next;
         index := sqldb.Fi('id');
         with TPageCrawl.Create(@threads,sqldb.Fs('adresa'),index,sqldb) do;
         if threads = THREADS_MAX then break;
       end;
       LeaveCriticalSection(critical);
     except
       LeaveCriticalSection(critical);
       Continue;
     end;
   end;

   Write(logo);
   Sleep(1000);
  until (threads = 0) and (urlcount  < 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have defined critical sections for each of the threads

They must all use the same critical section in order to lock properly. If they all have their own critical sections then the locks are only applicable to themselves.

I assume your thread is in `TPageCrawl`, you can pass in the critical section in the call:

```
TPageCrawl.Create(critical,@threads,sqldb.Fs('adresa'),index,sqldb)
```

Then in your thread proc you can `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()` as needed.

Comment: Note that these API calls are wrapped up for you in the `TCriticalSection` class which makes working with them a bit easier. There's also `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` for more complicated needs.

Comment: I am using free pascal I need a cross platform solution so this works fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

> I have defined critical sections for each of the threads including the main thread.

That's not how it works. You need to have a single shared critical section object. Each thread must use the same critical section in order for the serialization to work. You need to have a one-to-one relationship between critical section objects and resources that need protection.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530.aspx):

> A critical section object can be owned by only one thread at a time, which makes it useful for protecting a shared resource from simultaneous access.

Comment: the stupid part is that I worte the code using a shared critical section but received an access violation and blamed the shared critical section. Manny thanks!